# Create a dynamic jcarousel that resizes vertically

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

I'm using the jcarousel library (http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/) and wanted to use the vertical carousel, but also make it dynamically resize based on the height of the browser window.

There was an example page that had a horizontal carousel that stretched/shrunk to fill the width and showed more/less items as a result.

http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_callbacks.html

I took that example page and modified it to make it a vertical carousel and set the height's instead of widths to be %.  Here is the modified page:

http://www.strangeport.com/jcarousel/static_callbacks.html

Unfortunately all it does is create a carousel that stretches to show all items in it and causes the browser to scroll.

I am new to JQuery so been trying to debug this with firebug - but having difficulties figuring out what is wrong.  Any help someone can offer would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT: Thanks to Marcus' solution, this is what I did to fix it (I edited this to include the fix code in a more readable format:**

fyi to anyone else looking to use this for Jcarousel (I used this in a page-resize and document ready function).

```
var galleryHeight = $(window).height() - 170; // just arbitrary offset for testing
$('.jcarousel-container-vertical').css('height', galleryHeight); 
$('.jcarousel-clip-vertical').css('height', galleryHeight);
```

The jcarousel needs to have the container and the clip-container's height's set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [jQuery's `.css()` method](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to dynamically resize the gallery container. You would do something like the following:

```
$('#myGalleryContainer').css('height', galleryHeight);
```

Comment: Thanks! I have a bit more tweaking to do to calculate the exact height I need relative to the page.  But that works perfectly - thanks!